# Opposite of this command

Tags: mysql

What's the opposite to this command? to remove the ip from hosts so it cant connect as root.

GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'some ip here' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm i just went into phpmyadmin users then selected the user with host i wanted to remove and it worked